# Como criar um dataset para trabalhar com classificação no keras

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dataset, keras, deep-learning

Eu tenho uma serie de imagens (12500 ao total) em formato rgb e quero criar um dataset para trabalhar no keras. Eu quero deixar elas em formato semelhante ao dataset do Mnist...com shape (12500,50,50).

Só que quando eu faço um reshape com o numpy ele fica com dimensão (5,50,50,1). Acredito que ele esta ficando com uma dimensão a mais devido aos fatos de minhas imagens estarem com 3 canais (r,g e b).

Como eu faço o meu dataset ficar com as dimensões (12500,50,50) com apenas um canal de cores?

Abaixo, segue meu código.

Grato pela atenção.

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np

X_data = []
files = glob.glob ("C:/Teste_datasets/PetImages/Cat/*.jpg")

for myFile in files:
    print(myFile)
    image = cv2.imread (myFile)
    X_data.append (image)

X_data = np.array(X_data).reshape(-1,50, 50,1 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao usar um classificador monocromático, faz-se necessário, de alguma forma, descartar informações. Imagino que esteja buscando com o `reshape`, descartar dois canais quaisquer e pegar um. O problema é que o método `reshape` não descarta valores, apenas tenta redimensionar a matriz. A razão desse redimensionamento não causar falhas, reside na funcionalidade da dimensão de tamanho`-1`, que faz com que o `reshape` infira o valor dessa dimensão, compensando as perdas na quarta dimensão, em aumentos na primeira dimensão.

Trocar o valor `-1` pela tamanho esperado

```
X_data = np.array(X_data)
X_data = X_data.reshape((X_data.shape[0], 50, 50,1))
```

causa um defeito de imediato.

### Solução

É possível descartar canais usando [slices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

```
X_data = np.array(X_data)
print(X_data.shape)
X_data = X_data[:,:,:,0]
print(X_data.shape)
```

```
[daniel@pc keras]$ python3 testeKeras.py 
(2, 50, 50, 3)
(2, 50, 50)
```

### Solução melhorada

Descartar canais dessa forma, pode acarretar em perda de informações importantes.
É preferível carregar imagens em escala de cinza diretamente, no lugar de fazer descarte de canais. Isso pode ser feito passando o parâmetro `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` para o método `cv2.imread`.

```
X_data = []
files = glob.glob ("<caminho>/*.jpg")
for myFile in files:
    image = cv2.imread (myFile, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    X_data.append (image)

X_data = np.array(X_data)
```

```
[daniel@pc keras]$ python3 testeKeras.py 
(2, 50, 50)
```