# Importar imagens de uma pasta Python no mesmo formato que MNIST

Tags: python, redes-neurais, keras

Eu preciso fazer um algoritmo de reconhecimento facial em Python utilizando Redes Neurais. O meu orientador me mandou utilizar **Keras** e analisar essa aplicação em que foi utilizado o `dataset Mnist`:

**Código da aplicação (retirado de https://keras.io/examples/mnist_cnn/):**

> Trains a simple convnet on the MNIST dataset.
>
> Gets to 99.25% test accuracy after 12 epochs (there is still a lot of
>   margin for parameter tuning). 16 seconds per epoch on a GRID K520 GPU.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 12

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Minha dúvida é como eu faço pra importar as imagens da mesma forma que nesse código, pois ele utiliza esta função `mnist.load_data()` para retornar o dataset: `(x_train, y_train)`, `(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()`

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Sua dúvida é sobre como separar os dados em dados de treino e dados de teste? Ou é sobre como transformar imagens genéricas em imagens úteis para ser utilizada com Keras?

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a [documentação do conjunto de dados do MNIST](https://keras.io/datasets/#mnist-database-of-handwritten-digits), o tipo de dados da imagem do dataset é uma matriz de uma imagem em escala de cinza, com [profundidade de cor](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profundidade_de_cor) de 8 bits. Uma forma conveniente de carregar as imagens consiste em usar a função `cv2.imread`, que permite carregar imagens em escala de cinza, e tem 8bits como profundidade de cor padrão.

## Passo-a-passo

1. **Determinando as dimensões de entrada** - arbitre qual será o tamanho das imagens que você irá utilizar, que será também as dimensões de entrada do classificador. Imagens de tamanho pequeno demais podem perder informações, e grande demais podem causar dificuldades no processamento
2. **Redimensionando o conjunto de dados** - uma vez determinado o tamanho das imagens a ser utilizado, você deve redimensionar/cortar cada imagem do conjunto de dados para ficar na dimensão certa da entrada da sua rede neural
3. **Carregando as imagens** - você pode usar o `opencv` para carregar as imagens, como  neste exemplo<sup>[1]</sup>:

```py
X_data = []

for nomeDerquivo in listaDeNomeDeArquivos:
    imagem = cv2.imread (nomeDerquivo, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    X_data.append (imagem)

X_data = np.array(X_data)
```

A função `cv2.imread` já retorna uma matriz do `numpy`, de modo que será possível utilizar junto ao `keras` sem maiores dificuldades. Para usar os três canais de cores (Azul, Verde e Vermelho) ao invés da escala de cinza, remova o argumento `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` da chamada da função.

4. **Separando os dados de treino e de teste** - se desejar, faça a separação dos dados de treino e de teste. Isso pode ser feito utilizando a função [`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) do `scikit-learn`. Exemplo de uso:

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_data, y, test_size=0.30)
```

---

<sup>[1] Exemplo adaptados [daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/391414/49891)</sup>